# Invalid Podfile file: undefined method `enable_user_defined_build_types!'

Tags: cocoapods

I have installing gem on a Macbook Pro running Big Sur and M1 chip. I have followed the instructions given, added these two lines on top of my Podfile

```
plugin 'cocoapods-user-defined-build-types'
enable_user_defined_build_types!
```

then I am running the command

```
sudo gem install 'cocoapods-user-defined-build-types'
```

and gem is getting installed see below -

```
Successfully installed cocoapods-user-defined-build-types-0.0.7
Parsing documentation for cocoapods-user-defined-build-types-0.0.7
Done installing documentation for cocoapods-user-defined-build-types after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

Now, as soon as I run pod install, I get this error -

```
[!] Invalid Podfile file: undefined method `enable_user_defined_build_types!' for #<Pod::Podfile:0x0000000145251098 @defined_in_file=#<Pathname
```

Any idea what excatly is the problem here?

Answer (score 26):

### **I solved this issue by installing specific version of cocoapods with gem.**

Open a terminal in your Xcode project folder and run the commands below:

1. `gem cleanup`
2. `brew uninstall cocoapods`
3. `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods`
4. `sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.10.0 -n /usr/local/bin`
5. `sudo gem install cocoapods-user-defined-build-types`
6. `pod install --repo-update`

NOTE! If you using **react-native** before `pod install --repo-update` delete your `node_modules` folder and install again using `npm`

Comment: If your `gem` commands aren't working, try installing ruby first - just a simple `brew install ruby` willd do.

Comment: as of Jan 2023, [!] `React` requires CocoaPods version `>= 1.10.1`, which is not satisfied by your current version, `1.10.0`.
with 'sudo gem install cocoapods' I installed available CocoaPods 1.11.3 and it worked like a charm.

Comment: I had this weird issue that came from nowhere. Only these steps solved it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

add `gem 'cocoapods-user-defined-build-types'` to your gemfile and run `bundle install`

this should work if the other solutions didn't

Answer (score 0):

**I was struggling to get a solution,**

I was trying to install the snapkit and Firebase through cocoapods, I got pod init, but after insert inside the podfile  the e.g. Snpakit   when I tried  the comand pod install i got this issue
[!] Invalid Podfile file: undefined method......

What solved for me

- I installed the brew through terminal and by brew I reinstalled cocoapods

another thing that was crucial...
when I typed insert my pod

pod 'SnapKit', '~> 5.6.0'

The Podfile, automatically change de first character  to uppercase

**P**od 'SnapKit', '~> 5.6.0'

After you type your pod, try to leave the word pod in lowercase, after save and close, go to terminal and try again pod install

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React Native, here is a solution that might help you:
If your default Ruby env is 2.6, this is being used by the Mac and Xcode. Therefore, adding a new ruby env manager to your PC will be really helpful here.
Steps to follow:

- `brew install rbenv ruby-build`
- `rbenv init` (this gives a script that needs to be added into your ~/.zshrc or ~/.bash_profile)
- `echo 'eval "$(rbenv init - zsh)"' >> ~/.zshrc`
- To install latest Ruby env: `rbenv install -l`
- `rbenv global 3.1.2`  (or any version that you are installing)

Now, you can refer to @igroza's solution as follows:
Open a terminal in your Xcode project folder and run the commands below:

- `gem cleanup`
- `brew uninstall cocoapods`
- `sudo gem uninstall cocoapods`
- `sudo gem install cocoapods -v 1.10.0 -n /usr/local/bin`
- `sudo gem install cocoapods-user-defined-build-types`
- `pod install --repo-update`

**NOTE!**: If you using react-native before `pod install --repo-update` delete your node_modules folder and install again using npm